# Proving that $\mathbb{S}^n$ is the one-point-compactification of $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Prove that $\mathbb{S}^n$ (with the subspace topology) is the one-point-compactification of $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}$ where $p \in \mathbb{S}^n$.

Note that I've already shown on my own that $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}$ is locally compact.

*Proof:* Consider $(\mathbb{S}^n, \kappa)$ where $\kappa$ is the subspace topology on $\mathbb{S}^n$. Now consider the one-point compactification $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\} \cup \{p\} = \mathbb{S}^n$ equipped with the topology $\mathcal{T} = \{\text{open subsets of } \ \mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}\} \cup \{ U \subseteq \mathbb{S}^n \ | \ \mathbb{S}^n \setminus U \text{ is a compact subset of } \mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}\}$. I claim that $(\mathbb{S}^n, \kappa)$ is homeomorphic to $(\mathbb{S}^n, \mathcal{T})$

Since $\{p\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $p \in \mathbb{S}^n$ and $\{p\} = \mathbb{S}^n \cap \{p\}$ it follows that $\{p\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{S}^n$. Thus $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}$ is open in $\mathbb{S}^n$. Thus the open subsets of $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}$ are all open in $\mathbb{S}^n$ with the subspace topology.

We now claim that $$\{\text{neighborhoods of $p$ in $(\mathbb{S}^n, \kappa)$}\} = \{ U \subseteq \mathbb{S}^n \ | \ \mathbb{S}^n \setminus U \text{ is a compact subset of } \mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}\}$$

Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $p$ in $(\mathbb{S}^n, \kappa)$ then $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus U$ is closed in $(\mathbb{S}^n, \kappa)$ and since $(\mathbb{S}^n, \kappa)$ is compact it collows that $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus U$ is compact and moreover $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus U \subseteq \mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}$, thus $\{\text{neighborhoods of $p$ in $(\mathbb{S}^n, \kappa)$}\} \subseteq \{ U \subseteq \mathbb{S}^n \ | \ \mathbb{S}^n \setminus U \text{ is a compact subset of } \mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}\}$.

Conversely let $V \subseteq \mathbb{S}^n$ be such that $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus B$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}$ we show that $V$ is a neighborhood of $p$ in $(\mathbb{S}^n, \kappa)$. Since $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus V$ is compact and $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by the Heine-Borel theorem we have that $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus V$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and thus $\mathbb{S}^n \cap \left(\mathbb{S}^n \setminus V\right)= \mathbb{S}^n \setminus V$ is closed in $(\mathbb{S}^n, \kappa)$. Furthermore $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus V \subseteq \mathbb{S}^n \setminus\{p\} \implies p \in V$. Putting all this together we see that $V$ is a neighborhood of $p$ in $(\mathbb{S}^n, \kappa)$ and thus we've shown that $\{\text{neighborhoods of $p$ in $(\mathbb{S}^n, \kappa)$}\} \supseteq \{ U \subseteq \mathbb{S}^n \ | \ \mathbb{S}^n \setminus U \text{ is a compact subset of } \mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}\}$ and proven our claim above.

Thus $$\mathcal{T} = \{\text{open in $\mathbb{S}^n$ not containing $p$}\} \cup \{\text{open sets in $\mathbb{S}^n$ containing $p$}\}$$

and it's clear to see that $\mathcal{T} = \kappa$. Thus $(\mathbb{S}^n, \kappa)$ is indeed homeomorphic (through he identity map) to $(\mathbb{S}^n, \mathcal{T})$ and thus  $\mathbb{S}^n$ (with the subspace topology) is the one-point-compactification of $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus \{p\}$ where $p \in \mathbb{S}^n$. $\square$

---

Is the above proof correct and satisfactory? I know I've skipped a few details, as including those details would make the proof quite lengthy.

An easier proof (that I only realized after writing the above proof) would be to use the following theorem:

> *Theorem:* If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and $Y$ is compact Hausdorff such that for some point $p \in Y$, $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y\setminus \{p\}$, then $Y$ is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $X$.

and then the proof becomes a lot simpler I believe.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1300027

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that last theorem is allowed to use, your statement is an immediate corollary of it. In your setup you only need note that $X=\mathbb{S}^n\setminus \{p\}$ is locally compact, and the identity is the homeomorphism, and then the conclusion is that $\mathbb{S}^n$ is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $X$, as required. It's way easier than reproving part of that theorem as you do in the first part, slightly sloppily.

Answer (score 0):

[Stereographic projection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection)  is easy to visualize for $S^2\setminus \{p\}$; and the notion can be extended to $S^n\setminus \{p\}$...

This "shows" that $S^n$ can be thought of as the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R^n$ (or in your case, $S^n\setminus \{p\}$).